# Vim open file under cursor

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open file from complete path under cursor in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849846/open-file-from-complete-path-under-cursor-in-vim)

Let's say I have the following file tree:

```
/
  include/
    library/
      a.hpp
      b.hpp
  src/
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
```

And the following `/src/a.cpp` file:

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"
```

I always open Vim at the root directory. So when I want to load `a.hpp` I do :

```
:tabnew include/library/a.hpp
```

or:

```
:tabnew **/a.hpp
```

I'd like to map `<F4>` to open the file under the cursor in a new tab, using a recursive search.

I tried the following mapping command:

```
:map <F4> :tabnew **/expand("<cfile>")<cr>
```

But obviously, this can't work, as it tries to open the file `"/expand("` instead.

Any clue on how I could do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:help gf` gives a hint at how to accomplish this.

`:nmap <F4> :tabe **/<cfile><cr>`

It seems `<cfile>` is automatically expanded in mappings.

Comment: This can't work (and doesn't work) because `<cfile>` is evaluated by the `:execute` command and not when the mapping is used.

Comment: Bah, you are right.  It works fine when you define the map while the cursor is on your test case ;)

Comment: I just found it out and then saw your edit ! Thanks anyway ;) I'll accept that.

Comment: I've cleaned up this answer to remove the incorrect info for future searches.

Comment: I would use ```<C-w>gf```