# Open file from complete path under cursor in Vim

Tags: vim, command

If I have a file that contains a complete path for a file, is there a way to highlight the filename (using visual mode) and open the file (preferably in a split screen)?

Here is the behavior I would like:  if the file name contains a `/` character, assume it is a full path (i.e. the current directory is root). Otherwise, use the current folder (i.e. default behavior). Is this possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Put the cursor on the filename and type `gf` (in command mode). Or use **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>** | **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>** to open in another window. See also `:help gf` (no, it's not your girlfriend).

Comment: also might use `gF` since it will look for linenumbers after the path too

Answer (score 10):

`gf` command opens file under cursor.