# Vim tab drop file under cursor

Tags: linux, vim

I'm working on a c++ project and using vim as editor.

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor I know I can use 
`<c-w>gf`   (Ctrl-w gf) 
to open under cursor or selection in a new tab, this is very nice, except 1 thing, multiple tabs of same file could be opened, while I prefer to **jump to it if already open**.

`:tab drop` can do the work ( http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_a_file_or_jump_to_it_if_already_open )

But how to combine `<c-w>gf` with `:tab drop` ?

[Vim open file under cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848130/vim-open-file-under-cursor) gives some clue, but it works only with under cursor, not with selection(visual mode).

I know this is a very specific question, hope someone can help !

Thanks!

Comment: Someone vote a negative for my question ? Can please give a reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found out from my other answer, emulating the `<C-w>gf` command is difficult, and there are many corner cases.

Another approach to obtain what you want still relies on the original `<C-w>gf` command to (unconditionally) open a new tab, and then check whether the same buffer is already open in another tab, and if so, close the current (new) tab page and instead go to the other one. This will cause a little bit of flickering, but should be much more robust.

```
nnoremap <C-w>gf <C-w>gf:call FavorExistingTabPage()<CR>

function! FavorExistingTabPage()
    let l:bufNr = bufnr('')
    for l:i in range(1, tabpagenr('$'))
        if l:i == tabpagenr()
            continue    " Skip current.
        endif
        let l:winIndex = index(tabpagebuflist(l:i), l:bufNr)
        if l:winIndex != -1
            " We found the buffer elsewhere.
            if l:i >= tabpagenr()
                let l:i -= 1 " Adapt to removal of tab page before the current.
            endif

            close!

            execute l:i . 'tabnext'
            execute (l:winIndex + 1) . 'wincmd w'
            break
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

Note: This uses the first window in the first tab page it can find; you could tweak the algorithm to prefer a buffer "nearest" to the current one instead.

Comment: Genius !
This works very well and I don't feel any flickering at all.
Thank you so much !

Comment: For some reason, this has stopped working in Vim 8.2. Using <Ctrlw>gf opens file in new tab regardless of whether there is a previously open tab of the same file or not.

Comment: Apologies. Got it to work fine under Vim 8.2 ! Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the [`:help 'switchbuf'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27switchbuf%27) functionality, namely the `usetab` value:

> ```
>      useopen      If included, jump to the first open window that
>                   contains the specified buffer (if there is one).
>                   [...]
>      usetab       Like "useopen", but also consider windows in other tab
>                   pages.
> ```

Unfortunately, the option does not apply to the `<C-W>gf` command. However, you can re-map it to use `:tab drop`:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-w>gf :execute 'tab drop' fnameescape(expand('<cfile>'))<CR>
```

To handle a different working directory, the current file's directory has to be prepended:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-w>gf :execute 'tab drop' fnameescape(expand('%:h') . '/' . expand('<cfile>'))<CR>
```

But then, absolute directories won't work any longer. To handle those, we could change to the current directory first:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-w>gf :execute 'cd' fnameescape(expand('%:h')) <Bar>  execute 'tab drop' fnameescape(expand('<cfile>'))<CR>
```

Even with that, the emulation I've given is not 100% identical. `gf` uses the `'path'` option to look up files, `<cfile>` does not. You'd have to implement that lookup on your own, using `findfile()`. An easier alternative would be `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-P`, but that one needs path expansion, and fails for regular files, whereas `gf` can handle both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! In folder `/somepath/`, I open a cpp file `/somepath/af/receive.h` using vim, there's one line like this in `/somepath/af/receive.h` `#include "DriverTool.h"` If I do `<C-w>gf` by putting cursor on `DriverTool.h` without the above `nnoremap`, it opens `/somepath/af/DriverTool.h`, however after the `nnoremap` above, `<C-w>gf` takes me to `/somepath/DriverTool.h` which is indeed empty. Do you know why is this ? Please the two times, the file paths are indeed different.

Comment: Ah, we'll need to handle different current working dir (I usually use `'autochdir'`, so this didn't occur to me). See my edit. There's also another caveat in handling the `'path'` option.

Comment: Thanks.
I tried `:nnoremap <silent> <C-w>gf :execute 'cd' fnameescape(expand('%:h')) <Bar>  execute 'tab drop' fnameescape(expand('<cfile>'))<CR>`.
This time it will find the right file even if it's in a different working directory, this is quite awesome.
However, seems `tab drop` doesn't work anymore, if I do 2 times `<C-w>gf` on same file path, then it will be opened in 2 times in 2 different tabs, which does just the same job as original `<C-w>gf` job. Do you know this is why ? Btw, how is your `autochdir` working ?

Comment: I just did set autochdir, and now your first command `:nnoremap <silent> <C-w>gf :execute 'tab drop' fnameescape(expand('<cfile>'))<CR>` will open equally the right file, however the tab drop inside doesn't work all the time.
If I do 2 times <C-w>gf on same file path, like 
`etm/Types.h` of `#include <etm/Types.h>` then `etm/Types.h` will be opened 2 times in 2 different tabs.
But `Main.h` will only be open 1 time, on `#include "Main.h"`, thus it works on absolute path, but not on files under `path` ?

Comment: As I said, this answer doesn't work at all with `'path'`. And yes, functionality that involves the current working directory are difficult to implement, also as there are still some bugs in Vim around `'autochdir'`. Too bad that your file structure is too complex to be handled by this. I've got an alternative idea, maybe that will suit you better.